# How does one reduce the height of fontawesome text?

Tags: css, font-awesome

My site is using fontawesome. On the site, one of the icons (fa-arrows-h) is wrapped in a `span` tag, basically like this:

```
<span id="myArrow">
    <i class="fa fa-arrows-h"></i>
</span>
```

I have various styles set for this arrow in an external stylesheet, including a :hover transition. Other styles include font-size 41px and the arrow has position absolute. I have also styled the cursor to be a "pointer" and for the red arrow to become orange (using the CSS3 style: transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;) on hover.

EDIT: Here are all the CSS rules:

```
#myArrow {
    display: none;
    font-size: 41px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    color: red;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}

#myArrow:hover {
    color:orange;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Here is some jQuery that fades the arrow In:

```
$("#myArrow").css({"left" : (o.left + 740) + "px", "top" : (o.top) + "px"}).fadeIn(500);
```

One annoying thing is that the hover effect occurs about 20px above/below the text. That is, when either the bottom of the cursor touches the arrow, or the tip of the cursor is roughly 20px below the arrow, the hover transition occurs.

I have tried various things, even setting the style for both the `span` and the `i` to

```
style="line-height:0;height:0"
```

and the arrow still appears, with the same hover issue as described above (I also tried this styling individually for both tags).

I thought the issue also might be with the css display, so I tried setting both the `span` and the `i` to

```
- block
- inline
- inline-block
```

with no success.

I also set both the tags to have padding:0 with no success.

Note that this 20px-away hover transition only occurs vertically; when approaching the arrow horizontally (from left or right) the hover transition occurs when the user has actually hovered over the icon.

Can anyone please suggest how I would make the hover transition occur when a user approaches this icon from above or below and actually hovers over the fontawesome icon, not when the cursor is 20px away?

Comment: To make it easier to replicate the problem, could you post all of the CSS styling rules that are being applied to the `<span>` and `.fa-arrows` elements?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle

Comment: I think I understand what's going on here. Just because you set a font size doesn't mean every font will fill it (`.` or `,` are good examples). the horizontal arrow only fill part of the area because of it shape, but the font area that contain it is still at 41px. Just add something like `.fa { background-color: #ddd; }` to see the whole font region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not super elegant, I simply changed the `#myArrow`'s height and set its overflow to hidden then I used margins to position the `i` element within.

```css
#myArrow {
    font-size: 41px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    color: red;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}

#myArrow:hover {
    color:orange;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#myArrow {
    height:20px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#myArrow i {
    margin-top:-10px;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<span id="myArrow">
    <i class="fa fa-arrows-h"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly...seems elegant to me :)